# How to fetch max value from json column in mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table called **exercises** which has the following structure

| exercise_id | sets |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"repititions": "50"}, {"repititions": "50"}, {"repititions": "50"}, {"repititions": "50"}] |
| 2 | [{"repititions": "25"}, {"repititions": "25"}, {"repititions": "25"}, {"repititions": "25"}] |
| 3 | [{"repititions": "50"}, {"repititions": "50"}, {"repititions": "80"}, {"repititions": "50"}] |

The sets columns is JSON type. I want to fetch exercise with the max repititions i.e exercise_id 3 with 80 repititions.

**MYSQL VERSION** 5.7.24

Comment: You'll have to use [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html). But it would be easier if you store this data in normal rows and columns, and stop using JSON.

Comment: Why not simply normalise your schema?

Comment: It already has loads of data in there and would require a major refactor.

Comment: Then there's no time to lose. If you store data in a way that you don't know how to query, then you need to refactor it one way or another.

Comment: Agreed @BillKarwin. Will look for a refractor

Answer (score 1):

We discussed this already in the comments above, but for the record I can't think of a good way to solve this query in MySQL 5.7, the version you are using.

In MySQL 8.0, you must use JSON_TABLE():

```
SELECT e.*
FROM exercises,
JSON_TABLE(e.sets, '$[*]' COLUMNS(
  repetitions INT PATH '$.repetitions'
)) AS j
ORDER BY j.repetitions DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But since you aren't using MySQL 8.0, and I assume upgrading to MySQL 8.0 isn't in your short-term plan, you need another solution.

The solution I would use is to forget about storing data in JSON format. Refactor to a normal table, with one row per exercise set.

```
CREATE TABLE exercise_sets (
  exercise_id INT,
  set_id INT,
  repetitions INT
  PRIMARY KEY (exercise_id, set_id),
  KEY (repetitions)
);
```

Then the query is much easier to write:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM exercise_sets AS s
JOIN exercises AS e USING (exercise_id)
ORDER BY s.repetitions DESC LIMIT 1;
```